# Contours opencv c++ Assertation failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4)

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I finished this code up over an hour ago, tested it and it worked. When I was back It didnt work anymore and give me the error shown above. Went to grab a quick bite, came back and tried to run it again and suddenly it worked again. But now it once more refuses to run and keeps popping me the same error.

Im using my webcam as a standard input device and it works fine if I try to run a different program with the same code to commence the video feed.

I honestly have no clue what is going on here, my code should be working..
Anyone that can help out?

[image: received error]

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Function header
void thresh_callback(int, void* );

/** @function main */
int main( int argv , char** argc )
{

VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return 0;

Mat edges;
namedWindow("edges",1);

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

while(1)
{
    RNG rng(12345);
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor(frame, edges, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 120, 3);
    findContours( edges, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

    /// Get the moments
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false ); }

    /// Get the mass centers:
    vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
    { mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 ); }

    /// Draw Contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( edges.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
    circle( drawing, mc[i], 4, color, -1, 8, 0 );
    }

    /// Show in separate window
    namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Contours", drawing );

    /// Calculate the area with the moments 00 and compare with the result of the OpenCV function
    printf("\t Info: Area and Contour Length \n");
    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
    {
    printf(" * Contour[%d] - Area (M_00) = %.2f - Area OpenCV: %.2f - Length: %.2f \n", i, mu[i].m00, contourArea(contours[i]), arcLength( contours[i], true ) );
    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255)   );
    drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
    circle( drawing, mc[i], 4, color, -1, 8, 0 );
    }

    imshow("edges", edges);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Right after `cap >> frame`, do a sanity check: what do `frame.empty()` and `frame.channels()` return at that point? Also, try writing the frame to a file using `imwrite("temp.jpg", frame)`. What do you get?

Comment: well temp.jpg shows me that the image cant be shown because the file is empty. Am I just supposed to print frame.empty() and frame.channels() out in my console?

Comment: Yes that would work. What do you get?

Comment: well if I do it like this _italic_ **bold** ' return(frame.empty());
        return(frame.channel());' I get a message saying that 'class cv::mat has no member named 'channel''. But if I just return(frame.empty()); I get a 1.

Comment: yeah @Aurelius I think that might be it. But I just dont get how it can go from working to bugged out and back..

Comment: So it turns out the image is empty. Hmm... make sure that no other program is using the camera. If you have more than one camera (e.g. webcam + USB cam on a laptop), disable the one that you don't want to use (look up the cameras in the Device Manager), and then try again